# Search & Replace trailing strings

Tags: search, the-content, excerpt, customization

I need to filter the_content/the_excerpt and search & replace the following prepared array:

```
$searchArray = array("foo", "bar", "foo bar", ...);
```

My problem is the fact, that using php's **str_replace()** function it doesn't replace trailing strings like "foo bar". Instead it replaces only the "foo" without checking for the "foo bar" to be replaced. I understand why but I'm not sure how to solve this?

```
$content = str_replace(array_keys($searchArray), $replaceArray, $content);

add_filter('the_content', 'my_search_and_replace_function');
```

Comment: How does this require WordPress knowledge? I can see this as a pure PHP array/string manipulation problem ( namely one of search term order )

Comment: True it could be a PHP problem. I'm simply using it within WordPress and that's why I created my question here...